# Passing a struct with constant data to a function in C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I have code with a loop that calls a function with a compile time constant structure. I am aware that one must use a *compound literal* in order to have an anonymous struct (or array) literal.

Since a compound literal has the lifetime of the scope it was created in, I was concerned that using a compound literal might cause the struct to be unnecessarily recreated and destroyed each time the loop runs. To avoid this, I moved the struct to a variable outside the loop.

```
struct Struct {
    int x, y, z;
};
extern void func(struct Struct);
void test1(void) {
    for (int i = 1000000; i--;)
        func((struct Struct){1, 2, 3});
}
void test0(void) {
    const struct Struct s = {1, 2, 3};
    for (int i = 1000000; i--;)
        func(s);
}
```

I [tested the above](https://godbolt.org/z/9bYTqKE1W) via Godbolt, and as expected, `test1` seems to construct the data inside the loop. I also expected an optimizing compiler to identify this construct and optimize accordingly, so I added `-Os`, but the functions still [differ in assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/PcKWGWc4f), despite having identical behavior.

I was told that an optimizing compiler should generate **optimal** (and thus identical) code for constructs with identical behavior.

**Which option is actually more likely to offer better performance?**

Comment: Note that Clang generates the same assembly in both cases: https://godbolt.org/z/MYeTq3qGG

Comment: Removing the `const` will also generate identical assembly for both C and C++ in GCC. It seems GCC adheres to a footnote of the C standard, that allows for `const` objects to be placed in "read-only memory": http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note132

Comment: `-Os` optimizes for *size*. Try `-O2`.

Comment: *Which option is actually more likely to offer better performance?* - it depends on compiler missed optimization bugs in specific versions of different compilers.  There is no general answer; compilers *should* be making identical asm for this.  And it's silly for GCC to be loading that constant data from memory, instead of `mov esi, 3` inside the loop.  `mov r12, 0x200000001` outside the loop makes more sense than loading a constant, too.  The first option looks good with `gcc -Os` for x86-64, and still better with `-O3` but that deoptimizes to loading a from memory.

Comment: As long as you are passing by value, the object is going to be recreated, or at least recopied, on every iteration.  So the way to really avoid that is to modify `func` to accept a `const struct Struct *` instead.  Of course, if `func` actually needs to modify its private copy, then you can't do this and the copy is completely unavoidable.

Comment: @NateEldredge But could an *additional* copy be avoided by using the latter approach?

Comment: That's what the other answers address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which option is actually more likely to offer better performance?

It depends on compiler missed optimization bugs in specific versions of different compilers.  There is no general answer; compilers *should* be making identical asm for this.

And it's silly for GCC to be loading that constant data from memory, instead of `mov esi, 3` inside the loop.  `mov r12, 0x200000001` outside the loop makes more sense than loading a constant, too.  The first version looks good with `gcc -Os` for x86-64.  With `-O3` it gets worse, but is still not as bad as the way GCC compiles the 2nd version where it loads both from `.rodata`.

When you find different asm for equivalent source, usually it's either a missed optimization or two different but valid tuning choices.  In this case loading from memory is a missed optimization bug in GCC, which you should report (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/, use the keyword [missed-optimization]).

Clang gets it right in both cases: https://godbolt.org/z/TP1Mdx6vn

```
test1:                                  # @test1
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax       # dummy push to align the stack
        mov     ebp, -1000000
        movabs  rbx, 8589934593
.LBB0_1:                               # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rdi, rbx
        mov     esi, 3
        call    func@PLT
        inc     ebp
        jne     .LBB0_1            # }while(++i != 0)

        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

It makes some sense to hoist the 10-byte `mov r64, imm64` instruction out of the loop, like clang and GCC have been doing.  It can take an extra cycle to fetch from the uop cache on Sandybridge-family, according to [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/).  The loop runs many iterations, plenty to amortize the extra cost of saving/restoring another call-preserved register.

But `mov esi, 3` is only a 5-byte instruction, plenty cheap enough to just leave it in the loop, even if `func` is actually very short so this turns out to be a pretty tight loop.

---

When GCC or clang want a 64-bit constant in an integer register, they normally use `mov`-immediate.  Something about the 64-bit value being 2 struct members seems to be confusing GCC into loading it from `.rodata` in some cases.

But with `-Os` (optimize for size) it's able to avoid that, which is kind of surprising.  It's true that a 10-byte `mov`-immediate is smaller total size than 8 bytes of data plus a 7-byte `mov r64, [rip+rel32]` (REX + opcode + ModRM + rel32).

But if it's able to see a mov-immediate as an option at all, IDK why it wouldn't pick it for performance when GCC would normally do that when calling `int foo(uint64_t, int)`.

Compilers are very complex pieces of machinery, and work by transforming internal representations of the program logic.  Often they arrive at the same efficient result from different starting points, but not always.